# How to write a lead from a bassliine below

Tags: theory

Is there a rule for writing melodies from a bassliine below? I ask because I don't know if the same notes can be used, it has to be different etc., I have no problem writing bass lines. That they have a good groove that they sound good that they have a rhythm, But I need to know how to write a melody after the bassline.

Comment: What style are we talking about?

Comment: The question is way too broad. What have you tried so far, and what concrete problems did you encounter?

Comment: Hehe, there can be many, many, many rules. They vary by musical context (baroque counterpoint, rock guitar solo, etc.). I'm voting to close this question as impossible to answer, but that vote can be withdrawn after editing. You might want to read about [what this site focuses on](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to get the best answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: tbh, the way this is worded makes me think it's going to be EDM…

Answer (score 1):

The basics are the same in most music styles. The theory is covered in the various types of two-part counterpoint. Salzer's book "Counterpoint in Composition" is one of the standard modern treatments. The early chapters tend to be a bit dry; these are designed to develop a basic feeling for the sound of intervals and so are restricted in style. Gauldin't book on Eighteenth  Century Counterpoint is also good. Just for basic melody writing, Goetschius' book "Exercises in Melody Writing" (or some similar name) is good if a bit old (but there are free pdfs on the net.) Another resource available on the net is the discussion of "partimenti." These are exercises (mostly from the 1600s to 1800s) in making a piece of music over a given bass line. The principles are the same as in modern pop or country (or Latin or jazz, etc.) but the details are different.

Knowing how to improvise two-part counterpoint also helps one play a bass line against a given melody.

There are a few principles that are useful in helping the bass support the melody while keeping the two lines independent. Following these principles doesn't guarantee good music, but violating them usually sounds bad (it sounds like either the bass or soloist dropped out.)

The most important principle is to approach all perfect intervals (octaves, fifths, fourths, and their octave equivalents) by contrary motion. A bass line walking C, D, E, G doesn't work well with a melody going G, A, D, C, for example.

In reading a bass line, one must determine what the bass note represents. On strong beats, the bass note will usually be the root of the prevailing chord, or  (maybe 10-25% of the time) it will be the third. In patterns like oom-pah-pah (or boom-chick), the fifth of the chord will be played making an arpeggio. Also, a walking bass line will contain passing or neighbor notes.

One more point is that the melody will (in general) be much more lively than the bass line.

Answer (score 0):

I get that you're nor referring to classical style from the words groove and rhythm. So if strict counterpoint is not what you are after here is a general guideline to follow:

Make sure that you have a consonant interval (between bass and melody note) on strong beats. Use your ears!!

*consonat interval= 3rd or 5th or 6th.

P.s. 3rds and 6ths are your friends, play with them!